What is the best exponential backoff base in terms of probability of shortage of service?
Suppose you have a function s(t), where t is time, and return value is either 0 or 1, where 0 - means shortage of desired service, and 1 means it is available. The task here is to create function f(t1)=t2 where t1 - start of shortage and t2 - end of shortage AND using as low as possible number of predictions overall in [t1,t2] interval. Exponential backoff seems reasonable in this case, because it can predict shortages really well, but what would be the best base for it?
We can also specify availability of service through integration of s(t) => S(t) and logically conclude it is (S(b)-S(a))/(b-a) = 95% on entire timeline for example.
All that comes to mind is using calculus, and from calculus (I just created some s(t) myself and tried to insert some bases into f(t)=t+d*2^n) I have concluded phi (golden ration) somehow is better than base 2, but if anyone here is good in math, he could probably do it better and explain why it is so....please help me with this =)
disclaimer: it could or couldn't have real applications because there is such thing as jitter in backoff and exponential backoff is itself useful only on high intervals, and frankly base 2 is just bitwise shift instead of float manipulation, but I`m just really curios if it is possible to do in math.

Can you clarify a few things? How does f(t1) predict anything? How does exponential backoff predict anything?

And what is a shortage of a service?

Sure! We in development often set up some kind of retry behaviour (wait 1 min, then try again, or wait 1 minute, then 2 minutes, then 4, etc) if things fail. For example database can go down for "some" time, and database provider ensures that his database will be available 95% of the time. Well, this "retry" function is often just stone&sticks solution, but not optimal, because we either wait too long than necessary or retry to many times than necessary. f(t1)=t2 means that if we detected shortage on t1 - we can predict t2 where shortage is gone and database available.

Wait for storm to calm down basically, but for this we need to "send" some deadmans on the deck and detect that storm is calmed down, because "food" is low and we need to move. If you seen Three Body Problem movies, thats basically the same situation - to wait for chaos era to end.

I don't think this question is answerable for arbitrary functions s - whatever base one chooses, one can find a function s which will not play well with the prediction. Moreover, I am sure software engineers are not the best experts for this - this is a math question. Assumed you can give some constraints for s, I guess you could get better answers in one of the Stackexchange math forums. If you decide to ask there, please delete your question here beforehand, for not creating a cross post.

Can you clarify what you are asking? Exponential backoff is a heuristic used if you cannot predict when the component is back in working condition. Solving this theoretically should be pointless because it means EB isn’t suitable - if you know when the service comes back you restart then, which isn’t exponential but constant backoff.
